# Aborting execution of code in R(-Studio)

Tags: r, rstudio, abort

I'm using RStudio for writing code in R. Usually I submit larger chunks of code by selecting it and pressing `Ctrl + Enter`. Now, When an error occurs (e.g. connection to a databse could not be established), I'd like to abort execution of the subsequent code.

I tried `stop()`, which works when all the code is in one line:

```
# 21 is not shown
42; stop("error"); 21;
```

But when the code spans multiple lines, the code is still evaluated:

```
# Here 21 is shown
42
stop("error")
21
```

Is the a way to abort execution of code when submitting larger chunks of code?

Comment: Put it into curly brackets `{}`

Comment: @DavidArenburg you should write that up as an answer - it would get my vote!

Comment: @NickKennedy OK added, though wasn't sure how to correctly formulate it.

Answer (score 4):

You can wrap your code between `{}` (curly brackets) as they are pretty much equivalent to your `;` chain.

```
{
  42
  stop("error")
  21
}
## Error: error
```

Here's a nice illustration from the documentations with a function like interface.

```
do <- get("{")
do(x <- 3, y <- 2*x-3, 6-x-y)
## [1] 0
x <- 3; y <- 2*x-3; 6-x-y
## [1] 0
```

Comment: As promised, I did upvote your answer; I then realised that just wrapping in curly braces doesn't print the results of each statement which might be what the OP wanted, and that writing a function to do so was a little outside the scope of the comment - hope you didn't mind me posting an alternative answer.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not help in my case. Sometimes I'd like to step the the code and sometimes I'd like to run larger chunks a once. When stepping through the code line by line (and forgetting to not jump over the opening brace) the code is executed only when I reach the closing brace.

Comment: Ok, try this then https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/205612627-Debugging-with-RStudio#entering-debug-mode-stopping

Answer (score 2):

@DavidArenburg's answer is certainly the most straightforward approach. However, it's not clear from your question whether you wanted to preserve the behaviour of printing the value of each statement as it was run which is what happens normally when you use Ctrl-Enter in RStudio. If you did want to do that, then your options would be:

1. Wrap each statement for which you want output within `print`

e.g.

```
{
  print(42)
  stop("error")
  print(21)
}

#[1] 42
# Error: error
```

2. Use a custom function to achieve this:

e.g.

```
block <- function(expr) {
  expr <- substitute(expr)
  for (i in seq(expr)[-1]) {
    y <- withVisible(eval(expr[[i]], parent.frame()))
    if (y$visible && i != length(expr)) print(y$value)
  }
  y$value
}

block({
  42
  stop("error")
  21
})

#[1] 42
# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : error
```

Note that in all cases, none of your statements will actually be executed until you finish the block.

For non-trivial blocks of code, the difference in execution speed is negligible compared to standard execution.

e.g.

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(block = block({
  a <- 1:1e6
  b <- rnorm(1e6)
  sum(a + b)
}), curly = {
  a <- 1:1e6
  b <- rnorm(1e6)
  sum(a + b)
})

#Unit: milliseconds
#  expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
# block 108.7961 130.2517 169.4891 176.8425 197.4749 299.4014   100
# curly 109.9183 134.3076 171.9430 174.7121 194.5748 292.5958   100
```

Comment: That's a nice function there, but I doubt OP actually want to print results, rather to run a code within that block until a `stop` occurs. In that case this function will be probably quite slow. Will see what they say.

Comment: @DavidArenburg thanks. Agree they may just want the block result. I've modified the code to perform closer to standard running of the commands. Output is only printed if it would normally be (i.e. isn't returned invisbily, as with assignment), assignments are made in the calling environment and the output of the whole function is the result of the last statement. I've also benchmarked it - overall, the cost of my code is a small proportion of the running time for non-trivial code. For trivial examples like the OP's one, clearly it adds quite considerable overhead.